# How to derive JSON instances for a type with dependent-map?

Tags: json, haskell, gadt

I use [`dependent-map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-map) to create a map of GADT values. My goal is to derive JSON instances for them. The [`aeson-gadt-th`](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/aeson-gadt-th) library can derive JSON instances for the GADT itself (the `P` type below); however automatic deriving for the map of GADT values (the `DMap P Identity` type below) fails because of missing `Generic` instance on this type: `• No instance for (Generic (DMap P Identity))`.

How do I generate `Generic` for this type?

```
import Data.Dependent.Map

data P a where
  P_Title :: P Text

deriveGEq ''P
deriveGCompare ''P
deriveJSONGADT ''P

deriving instance ToJSON (DMap P Identity)
```

---

**EDIT:** After using the `dependent-sum-aeson-orphans` library per Cale's answer below:

```
import Data.Dependent.Sum.Orphans ()

data MyType = MyType (DMap P Identity)
  deriving Generic

deriving instance ToJSON MyType
```

I see a different error:

```
• Could not deduce: Data.Constraint.Extras.ConstraintsFor'
                      P ToJSON Identity
```

If `DMap P Identity` already has JSON instances (per the orphan import) why does a simple type wrapper not?

---

**EDIT 2**: Okay, after some exploration of the code and examples of the referenced libraries I realized I needed to derive `ArgDict`, after which everything works!

```
import Data.Constraint.Extras.TH

deriveArgDict ''P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library here which has ToJSON and FromJSON instances for DSum and DMap.

https://github.com/obsidiansystems/dependent-sum-aeson-orphans

Be sure to have a look at how they work, it's a nice example of what can be done with [constraints-extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-extras-0.2.3.4/docs/src/Data.Constraint.Extras.html#ArgDict).